# Laravel 5 routing: admin, members, public

Tags: php, laravel, routes

My app should have admin, members and public areas, mapped from admin.mydomain.com, members.mydomain.com, and www.mydomain.com. Documentation contains the following example regarding to subdomain routing:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
  Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
    //
  });
});
```

But I don't want to hardcode or use some other way the 2nd level domain name in route (myapp.com in this example). So I made it this way:

```
Route::pattern('domain', '.+\..+');
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'domain' => 'admin.{domain}', 'middleware' => 'auth'],
  function () {
    Route::get('/edit/{id}/{name}', 'MyController@index');
});
```

Then I made a controller like

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    function index($id, $name) {
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

and when I navigate admin.mydomain.com/edit/1/alex, I get output "admin".
Of course it happens because I use {domain} as a pattern. But I don't want to receive domain as first argument in every action of all admin controllers. Please help me to do that right way.

Comment: I haven't tried this personally, but you should be able to just put a middleware in between the controller and the request itself. You won't be getting the first argument as the subdomain in the controller, unless you specifically wish to pass it on to some/all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be creating a middleware that will remove the `domain` parameter:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class RemoveDomainMiddleware {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)  {

    $request->route()->forgetParameter('domain');

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

then make sure your register the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //......
    'domain' => \App\Http\Middleware\RemoveDomainMiddleware::class,
    //.....
];
```

Finally, add the middleware to your group:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['domain', 'auth'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'domain' => 'admin.{domain}'],
  //.....
});
```

I hope this will help you.